# Is there any way to expand sub 'item'(not headline) tree cyclically?

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, is there any way to expand sub 'item'(not headline) tree cyclically? I tried hitting `TAB(org-cycle)`, but it expands headline and all sub item tree showed at once.

Here is the example. Let's say I have an org file like below.

```
* h1
  - i1
    - i2
      - i3
```

What I want is the key stroke X to expand sub item tree like below.

1. Open the org file. ('**|**' indicate the cursor)

   buffer shows:

   ```
   * h1|...
   ```
2. Press X.

   buffer shows:

   ```
   * h1|
     - i1...
   ```
3. Press X.

   buffer shows:

   ```
   * h1|
     - i1
       - i2...
   ```
4. Press X.

   buffer shows:

   ```
   * h1|
     - i1
       - i2
         - i3
   ```
5. Press X

   buffer shows:

   ```
   * h1|...
   ```

Is there any key storke like X?

Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in command for this. By default, `org-cycle` operates on either headlines or list items, depending on the current line. Since you are starting at a headline, `org-cycle` shows/hides the contents of that headline as text. If you move point down to the `i1` line I believe from there `TAB` will do what you want.

There is an option you can try: `org-cycle-include-plain-lists`. If you change the value to `integrate` it will get you closer to what you want (but not quite, see below).

To try it: `M-x customize-option org-cycle-include-plain-lists` and change the value to `As children of outline headings`.

Note that this does not give you exactly what you want. Read the doc for this option (`C-h v org-cycle-include-plain-lists`) for the details, it is not the default behavior because "This setting can lead to strange effects".

Comment: So I see the command does not exist by default.Thanks.